# Android App Do not allow user to copy long text from installed app to any editor

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing android app. It contains very long text. I don't want any user to copy this text and paste it to any editor. Can I use text box to display long text and disable text selection? Is there any hack using which still user can copy this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard setting for a TextView in Android is already non-selectable text. To be sure you can also set it explicitly (android:textIsSelectable="false").
If you want to use an EditText element, you have to disable editing and set "textIsSelectable" to false.

For just displaying Text you should use a TextView.

However it is not possible to completely avoid that someone can extract the text from the app, e.g. with a screenshot and a text recognition software/app you can always extract displayed text. Or one could extract the text from the APK.

Comment: If the text is very long, then user need to use snapshot many times and then need to send image to image recognition software to get the text. As per my understanding, user can not e tract text at one go.

Comment: Is it possible for the user to extract the text at one go? Text is extremely long and not fit to the window.

Comment: If the text is hardcoded (as resource or in the code itself) in the  application one could extract the text from the APK file itself. The APK file can be obtained using e.g. a rooted device. But this method will most certainly require a Computer to extract the text.